# How to do a collection property inside another collection in user control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, generics, collections, user-controls

I have a user control with a property "Rules" that is a generic list.
Every "rule" is associated to a combobox control and i have to create a property to host data for the combobox. I used another generic list to accomplish this.

In design works well, i can add items normally in property grid, but when i run the program the values are not maintained.

Rules property:

```
Private _regras As New List(Of ParametrosColunasGrid)
<Category("Ecletica")> _
<Browsable(True)> _
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property Regras() As List(Of ParametrosColunasGrid)
    Get
        Return _regras
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of ParametrosColunasGrid))
        _regras = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Class ParametrosColunasGrid
    '...

    Private _itens_Combo As New List(Of ItemComboBox)
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property ItensCombo As List(Of ItemComboBox)
        Get
            Return _itens_Combo
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of ItemComboBox))
            _itens_Combo = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '...
End Class
```

ItemComboBox Class:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class ItemComboBox
    Public Property Value As String
    Public Property Key As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _Value
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: what do you mean `when i run the program the values are not maintained` what do you want to happen?  There are a couple of problems there, but I am not sure what you are after.

Comment: Sorry, in another project a put the user control in a form, then I ran the program and checked the property "ItensCombo". The return was a list with two items (i have added in design), but the the items were equal to Nothing

Comment: you are missing some serialization code; there is nothing there for the ItemComboBox and you are missing some methods.  there are 2 good articles on CodeProject which will help.  [How to Edit and persist...](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) and a VB oriented one with a checklist at the end for this sort of thing: [Extended Collection editor Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework)

Comment: Thanks, i will study this articles, it's what i was looking for. For a while I have created a "DataSource" property and passed data by the code

Comment: there is a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24369553/1070452), but the evolution of his collection is spread across 1-2 others posts